# What type of product can I use to hang wall art on bare wood that won't damage the wall?

Tags: wood, interior, hanging

I have an "outdoor office" with bare wood interior walls. I'd like to hang some wall art but I'm concerned about damaging the wood and/or leaving a lot of holes that I would have to patch later (and would look unappealing since I don't want to paint).

Is there a type of product I can use to hang stuff that does NOT require piercing the wood surface?

Comment: Does the wood have any finish, such as shellac, varnish, polyurethane?

Comment: @bib yes, multiple coats of polyurethane

Comment: What is the weight of the art?

Comment: @warloki I'm not sure... a pound or two? It's a 18 x 20 inch metal frame with a glass surface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two approaches come to mind:

[Thin nail picture hooks](http://www.homedepot.com/p/OOK-34-Piece-Professional-Picture-Hanging-Value-Pack-50918/100039637?MERCH=REC-_-PIPHorizontal1_rr-_-100312631-_-100039637-_-N)

[image: ook]

These use very sharp, very thin hardened nails that can be removed leaving a hole so small it is nearly invisible, even in finished wood. If it were noticeable, it could be concealed with touch up wax. Various weight load sizes are available. The sizes that have the thinnest nails can hold at least 20 lbs. each, more if pairs of hooks are used.

[Removable hooks](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Command-White-Wire-Backed-Picture-Hanging-Hooks-3-Pack-17043/202362897?MERCH=REC-_-PIPHorizontal1_rr-_-203431562-_-202362897-_-N)

[image: removable hooks]

These are glue on devices in which the glue strip can be pulled to remove, supposedly doing no harm to the finish of the wall.  These hangers are limited to loads no greater than 5 lbs., but the use of two hangers would increase that load.

```
 Images and links are for illustration only, not an endorsement of goods or sources
```